# linq clause with multiple on clause with arithmetic

Tags: linq

I'm wondering how can I have a simple arithmetic within the "On" clause of linq.

```
from oldstatus in ctx.LoanStatHistory
join newstatus in ctx.LoanStatHistory
on 
    new {oldstatus.Loan_Id, oldstatus.Order} equals 
    new {newstatus.Loan_Id, (newstatus.Order - 1)}
select new {....}
```

I get a red underscore warning under (newstatus.Order - 1) and it states anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression

Answer (score 3):

You just need to give the second field in the second anonymous expression the same name as the field in the first expression:

```
from oldstatus in ctx.LoanStatHistory
join newstatus in ctx.LoanStatHistory
on 
    new {oldstatus.Loan_Id, oldstatus.Order} equals 
    new {newstatus.Loan_Id, Order = (newstatus.Order - 1)}
select new {....}
```

The name of the other fields are inferred from the properties you're using directly.